# Is it possible to use Dynamics CRM to develop an unrelated CRM software?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

While I'm learning Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015, I find out that there is a good built-in software infrastructure available to generate new modules.

Although the features available in the UI are so limited. But working with its SDK, seems it can be used as a tool to create software.

**Question1:** Is it appropriate to use Dynamics CRM to develop some software unrelated to CRM, for example, *Production Planning*, *Logistics*, *Warehousing*, *Accounting*, *Payroll Systems*,....

**Question2:** How does it compare to other solutions like using **DevExpress XAF**, **Light Switch** or solutions like these?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830281(v=crm.6).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, absolutely, especially with the latest updates to CRM 2015 Online (available On-Prem soon) that allow you to batch updates in database transactions. I have created Student Information solutions, Oil Well management solutions, Real-Estate solutions, Loan management solutions, Donation management systems and several other smaller solutions using the Dynamics CRM framework.
2. The biggest difference is in how you design solutions. Like any framework, almost anything is possible in CRM but you must design your solutions around the framework features. If you are using a lower-level framework like DevExpress or LightSwitch or even just .NET code, you will have much more power over your user interfaces and code. But with that power comes much more responsibility in maintenance and interface design. Once you get a handle on CRM, you can create almost anything quickly without worrying about the "plumbing." You just have to learn all the different framework features and the associated limitations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I'm really interested to use CRM as framework. But most of my concerns are around following topics. How to manage the customization which is spread over forms and entities? For example tracking changesets in web resources or business rules and versions via TFS (Not the whole Solution using Solution Packager). How to use a [Black-box database] solution? Are all the challenges discovered and resolved in a way that there will be no need to work with database directly at all?

Comment: There are two 3rd-party apps that I've used for change control. The most full-featured is ALM Toolkit from ADX Studios (http://www.adxstudio.com/adxstudio-alm-toolkit/). It allows you to export ALL of your CRM customizations, including entity metadata and even entity data if you like. The second is CRM Solution Manager (http://www.crmsolutionmanager.com) which works with Visual Studio. It allows you to work with anything to do with code (web resources, plugins, workflow activities, etc) inside VS, which then allows you to use your Source Control of choice (TFS, Git, etc).

Comment: And yes, in my ten years of CRM development I have never needed to access the database directly with a few exceptions: working with MS on a support ticket or SSRS reports that use the FilteredViews from the database (on-premise only).

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**
It is *definitely* possible to use CRM for completely unrelated things. At my current job as a Business Applications Consultant, we use CRM as a starting point and utilize:

- Plugins
- Web Resources (mostly JS)
- Workflows

These different things help us customize how the system works for each individual client. But more specifically your question, yes, we have developed systems for *warehouse management*.

**Question 2:** I cannot speak to the differences between these different things as I am only familiar with CRM.

That's only one opinion from a CRM Dev. Hope you get more and more!